# Copy Data Factory selected pipelines from Azure one subscription to other

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure

I have data pipeline in Azure Data Factory which copies the files from AWS S3 Bucket to Azure Data lake gen 2. So in order to build this pipeline I have created various resources like Azure Data Lake Gen 2 Storage, File system in ADLS with specific permissions, Data Factory, Source Dataset which connects to S3 Bucket, Target Dataset which connects to ADLS Gen2 folder.

So all these were created in a Dev subscription in Azure but now I want to deploy these resources in Prod subscription with least manual effort. I tried the ARM template approach which does not allow me to selectively choose the pipeline for migration. It copies everything present on the data factory which I don't want considering I may have different pipelines which are still under development phase and I do not want those to be migrated to Prod. I tried the powershell approach too which also has some limitations.

I would need expert advice on what is the best way to migrate the code from one subscription to other.

Comment: Are you using ADF v1 or v2?

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT : I am using V2